# how to solve [export display=:0] redhat?

Tags: linux, cron, redhat, gnome-terminal

I have shell script that require to run in the foreground but periodically , so  I am trying to combine crontab with the ability to spawn a new terminal window from it using this syntax :

```
export DISPLAY=:0 && /usr/bin/gnome-terminal -e "test.sh"
```

Where test.sh the shell script that I want to execute

Comment: Try this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25684/how-to-access-x-display-from-a-cron-job-when-using-gdm3

Comment: and this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10121/open-a-window-on-a-remote-x-display-why-cannot-open-display